# mysql colomn value in other column with extra value

Tags: mysql, merge

In my table in mysql, I have 4 columns, but I added one extra column. And the value of the last column must be the value of column 1 with extra value.

for example:

```
UPDATE users SET user = 'column_1_value'."00";
```

It's like merging column value with extra value.

Thanks inadvance !

Comment: Use `CONCAT(column1, '00')`

Answer (score 2):

since you did not provide enough context like the datatypes your table consists of I can just guess. If they are string types (like varchar) you can use concat:

```
UPDATE users SET column_4 = CONCAT(column_1, "00");
```